# CORS error happens only on certain XHRs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors

We have an SPA that draws more javascript modules from a separate backend server, assisted by Require.js. By nature of the XHR loading procedure, pre-flight OPTIONS requests are made to the backend server and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response is perfectly valid. The process of login and initial module loading work just fine, as expected.

> XHR finished loading: "http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceA".
>
> XHR finished loading: "http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceB".

Funny thing is, certain subsequent actions that call for more modules would unexpectedly raise a CORS error in Chrome.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceC. Origin
>   https://frontend.cloudapp.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Which does not make sense, since the previous modules loaded just fine. Even the actual OPTIONS preflight came back proper for resourceC. Some other places in the UI have their modules loading fine too. And Firefox does not appear to suffer from this problem. Has anybody experienced similar CORS errors?

**Request/response headers for successful (expected) module**

```
Request URL:http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceA
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Host:backend.cloudapp.net
Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 07:12:42 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET



Request URL:http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceA
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Content-Type:application/json
Host:backend.cloudapp.net
Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:5048
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 07:12:42 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**Request/response headers for unsuccessful module**

```
Request URL:http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceC
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Host:backend.cloudapp.net
Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 07:12:59 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET



Request URL:http://backend.cloudapp.net/api/modules/resourceC
Request Headers
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:https://frontend.cloudapp.net
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

(And browser blocks further action)
```

Comment: Can you share the request/response headers for the failing request (available in Chrome's Network tab).

Comment: The logged headers have been pasted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Chrome has gone through so many version updates, in addition to us deploying some module resources in a different package manner now in different AWS infrastructure, we no longer experience this problem now.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[Inspired from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66704654/1990505)

It might be worth investigating if any of the failing XHRs are sending any peculiar unicode character. In our case, one of our user's name contained a unicode character and our HTTP proxy wasn't handling it properly thereby leading to a CORS error.